# Package Control in Sublime3 not working?

Tags: sublimetext3

***Note: I´ve searched for sublime here at the forum first, in order to post a question, because I wasn´t sure if this question was adequate for this specific forum and wanted to compare it with other posts. If it shouldn´t be here, please tell me so, and I´ll gladly close it here and open it in any other stackoverflow´s forum. Thanks.***

I´ve just installed sublime3. After that I´ve installed package control.
But even when I try and install some packages using package control not all packages get installed, even when I get the "successfully installed" message at the bottom of the window.

*To install a new package I go to preferences/package control/install package, and after getting the "successfully installed message" I go to /list packages and it´s not there.*

I realised that maybe that´s because some packages are not compatible with sublime 3 (even there it shouldn´t be the successfully installed message there).

So, I´ve tried the [latest sublime3 version of emmet](http://emmet.io/blog/sublime-text-3/), but it seems that´s not working (I´ve tried some shortcuts without any success). So I´ve watched [Chris Coyer screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uIPGgq9R5Y) to check out if I´ve missed something, but it still won´t work.

I´ve tried installing it manually: I´ve went to C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages (I´ve installed the x64 package, but for some reason it´s not installed into \Program Files (x86)).
And then I copy/paste the unzipped folders of /emmet-sublime-master and /PyV8 (I´ve tried naming the folder just emmet).

And still, it won´t work. This kinda happened to me with a lot of packages, I´ve installes several of them, and when I go to preferences/package control/list packages, I get only 3 of them.

Comment: In the ST console, when you "install" a plugin or restart the editor, are there any errors? I'd also recommend filing an issue with the Package Control maintainers. For details on information they want, and where to create the issue, see https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/issues

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn´t thought on filing an issue with Package Control maintainers. Nope, there are no error at all, just the successfully installed plugin message.
Anyway, I´ve installed ST2 instead of the ST3 and everything works now. I´ve realised that many plugins are not yet ported to ST3 (http://www.caniswitchtosublimetext3.com/).

Comment: Only the supported packages should be listed when installing with ST3, so if you were seeing more, it is a bug for them. That being said, if nothing was installing, that's also an issue. I'm currently using ST3 with package control and everything seems to be working okay for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came across this issue as well. This thread   (https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/874) directed me to delete the entry for Package Control under "Ignored Packages" in my User Settings File.  Once that was deleted, I restarted, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

In SublimeText go to `Preferences` -> `Settings`. In the opened file `Preferences.sublime-settings` remove `Package Control` from `ignored_packages` list (see below). Save the file and restart Sublime.

```
{
    "font_size": 11,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage",
        "Package Control" <---- REMOVE
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, `Package Control` was already removed from `ignored_packages`, so that didn’t help. But the Sublime Text console held messages which indicated the problem. (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to open the console.)

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/myuser/.config/sublime-text-3/Cache/Package Control/merged-ca-bundle.crt'

And changing ownership on the `Package Control` directory allowed me to use Package Control again:

```sh
chown -R myuser:myuser '/home/myuser/.config/sublime-text-3/Cache/Package Control/'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, after try to remove and reinstall the Sublime and verified the ignored_packages, I installed python and restart the sublime. So it worked.

In Terminal:

```
sudo apt install python python3
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.