# How to set Package Controller in Sublime when it seems inactivated

Tags: macos, sublimetext4, package-control

## **Desired output:**

I would like to set Sublime Text 4 on my new MacOs with all my favourite plugins.
As already done with previous machines, I was about to install Package Control as described here https://packagecontrol.io/installation.

The installation is successful, as you can see by Sublime popup message and by the Sublime's installed packages path:
[image]
[image]

Anyway, it looks somehow inactivated.
When I press the command palette, no PC command is shown:
[image]

and from the menu, Package Control settings are in light gray:
[image]

As already mentioned in previous stackoverlflow questions, it could be because it is in ignored list of packages:
[Why is Sublime Package Control not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461198/why-is-sublime-package-control-not-working)
[Package Control in Sublime3 not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876710/package-control-in-sublime3-not-working)
But in my case, here is the setting file and package control isn't on that list:
[image]

I run out of ideas.
What else(see: already tried) can I do in order to install my plugins via Package Control?

## **Already tried**

- Uninstall/Reinstall Package Control
- Uninstall/Reinstall Sublime
- Install Sublime via homebrew
- Move Package Controll package from "Installed Packages" to "Packages"
- Install Control Package manually
- Install Control Package via GUI
- Install Control Package via Command Palette
- Install sublime 3

## Current settings

- MacOs 13.4.1
- Sublime text 4

Answer (score 0):

Use this package https://github.com/wbond/package_control/releases/download/4.0.0-beta8/Package.Control.sublime-package

Download and copy it to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Installed Packages

Restart and you're good to go.